# Bounding parameters in optimization problems

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The following outputs answers for a variety of cases for the parameters, `a` and `b`:

```
ArgMax[{a*Sqrt[x] + b*Sqrt[y], x + y <= 10}, {x, y}]
```

How can I tell Mathematica to only compute the case where `a > 0` and `b > 0`? The following basically works but still yields an additional case I don't want simply called true, for which the answer is indeterminate:

```
ArgMax[{a*Sqrt[x] + b*Sqrt[y], x + y <= 10, a > 0, b > 0}, {x, y}]
```

What is that? And how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FullSimplify[
 ArgMax[{a*Sqrt[x] + b*Sqrt[y], x + y <= 10 && a > 0 && b > 0}, {x, y}], a > 0 && b > 0]

(* {(10 a^2)/(a^2 + b^2), (10 b^2)/(a^2 + b^2)} *)
```

Comment: This is very useful. I do think it still calculates all of the extraneous cases and then discards them in the FullSimplify call, right? I will be using this in a few cases with many parameters, so there could be some cost to this, but it's probably not enough to worry about in using this attractively simple option.

Comment: @Shane as you surely know, `Solve` doesn't work the same way with the assumptions. Compare: `ArgMax[{a*Sqrt[x] + b*Sqrt[y], x + y <= 10 && a > 0 && b > 0}, {x, y}]` with `ArgMax[{a*Sqrt[x] + b*Sqrt[y], x + y <= 10}, {x, y}]`